# launching system tray application like normal app in the center of the screen

Tags: windows, notification-area

I have 49 inch monitor and system tray is not easy to reach. Is there a way I can launch system applications like Sound, Wireless, etc as direct application? Also, I would like to see the somewhere in the center of the screen rather than botton right corner.

[image: System Tray App]

Comment: No, the application tells windows that it doesn't want to be minimized to the taskbar and that it supports system tray functionality.  The best I can think of is to move the taskbar to the side or top of the screen.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, is there any way to move system tray itself. lower bottom is really becomes painful on bigger monitor.

Comment: Only by moving the entire taskbar.. and I feel your pain.. the explorer used to be much better.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, I found xbox gaming bar launched by with Win+G, is giving me at least audio right on top of the screen. Seems to be persisting window locations after moving.